# Understanding arr[::-1] in numpy. Is this a special case?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I realize that arr[::-1] returns a reversed view for arr. Further arr[st_index:end_index:increment] is a compact syntax for indexing while creating view. (BTW what is this way of indexing called?)

So if I have code like:

```
arr = np.array(range(10))
print(arr)  #prints: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Now, if I want to see the arr as reversed I can try (I don’t need to subtract 1 from len(arr)):

```
arr[len(arr)-1: 0: -1] #This gives o/p as: array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

The first element was not selected, which was expected. And if I change 0 to -1, i.e, if I try: `arr[len(arr)-1: -1: -1]` OR even `arr[:-1:-1]`, I get an empty array.

Apparently I get the reversed array view by: `arr[::-1]`

Q: How is this working? If I do not specify the first two arguments how does it infer that it needs to continue till 0? In fact it is just interpreting that it needs to go till the boundary as arr[::1] gives normal array.

Is this just coded as a special case or is there something more going on? And is there a way to get reversed array view by explicitly specifying the three expressions in indexing. i.e., are there any values for expr1, expr2, expr3 which can reverse arr in `arr[expr1:expr2:expr3]`?

Comment: *"what is this way of indexing called?"* - This is called [*slicing*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings).

Comment: Especially the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/509297/480982 of that question

Comment: Q: If I do not specify the first two arguments how does it infer that it needs to continue till 0? A: it internally sets the end to `-1`, but this is only triggered by passing `None`, you can't set it explicitly, see [source of `PySlice_GetIndices`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61d8c54f43a7871d016f98b38f86858817d927d5/Objects/sliceobject.c#L191)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic Python slice behavior:

```
In [1]: 'abc'[::-1]
Out[1]: 'cba'
In [2]: 'abc'[slice(None,None,-1)]
Out[2]: 'cba'
```

`numpy` has an 'indexing_tricks` object that can convert the slice notation to a slice object:

```
In [3]: np.s_[::-1]
Out[3]: slice(None, None, -1)
In [4]: np.s_[:-1]                # the common 'all but last' slice
Out[4]: slice(None, -1, None)
```

The interpreter converts the `::` notation to a `slice` object, using `None` for the omitted values.  The object's `__getitem__` method is responsible for using the `slice` (or tuple containing `slices`).  The correct start and stop can be inferred from the object's dimensions.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. It just repeats what OP has already observed with strings.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I showed the `slice` equivalent - which answers his last question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So to sum up it is a special case of slice (where this is a syntax of specifying slicing for array).

Comment: I'm  not sure I'd call is special.  To me it's more of a generalization, or logical application of the basics.